# Javascript variable posting to php, and its not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pos

I'm beginner of php and javascript so i dont really now whats the wrong in my code.
i just want to send a javascript variable to php and its not working, i dont now why. These files all different pages.
So its a click function in javascript:

file: SelectTableRow.js.

```
var productTable = document.getElementById('ProductTable'), rIndexB;

for(var i = 0; i < productTable.rows.length; i++)
{
    productTable.rows[i].onclick = function()
    {
        rIndex = this.rowsIndexB;
        var bAzon = this.cells[0].innerHTML;

        $.post("AddProductTable.php", {BAzon: bAzon}, function(){
        $('#load').load('AddProductTable.php');
        });

        console.log(bAzon);
    }
}
```

The database is running clear too.
The data what should display:

file: AddProductTable.php

```
<table class="DataTable">
    <th>Azonosito</th>
    <th>Név</th>
    <th>Mennyiség</th>
    <th>Mértékegység</th>
    <th>Ár</th>
    <th>Törlés</th>


<?php

require_once 'Connect.php'; // its 100% working.

$BAzon = $_POST['BAzon'];  // 0 result :(

if($result = $link_database->query("SELECT bevetAzon, termekAzon, bevettMennyiseg, bevettAr FROM bevetttermek WHERE bevetAzon = '$BAzon'"))
{
    $table = $result->fetch_all();

    foreach($table as $row)
    {   
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach($row as $record)
            {   
                echo "<td>".$record."</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
    }
}

echo "BAZON: ".$BAzon;  //0 result
echo "POST: ".$_POST['BAzon'];  // 0 result

?>
</table>
```

and the file where i call this(just the important part):

Index.php

```
<div id="load">

</div>
```

When im trying a test number, its working, display the datas.
Please help me, i cant go through this one.

Comment: open developer tools in your browser, open the Network tab and see that request once it's made - you can see what POST data is being sent to AddProductTable

Comment: Ohh, thanks, thats shows me, the datas are send. And its sent, but why i cant display? :( 

<table class="DataTable">

   <th>Azonosito</th>
   <th>Név</th>
   <th>Mennyiség</th>
   <th>Mértékegység</th>
   <th>Ár</th>
   <th>Törlés</th>
   

<tr><td>98</td><td>4</td><td>10</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>98</td><td>4</td><td>10</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>98</td><td>4</td><td>10</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>98</td><td>4</td><td>10</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>98</td><td>1</td><td>10</td><td>10</td></tr>BAZON: 98POST: 98

Comment: what's the names of the POST fields?

Comment: $BAzon = $_POST['BAzon'];  or what kinda of fields? :D

Comment: In your code you post your data to AddProductTable.php, but in the next line you get a completely fresh AddProductTable.php with no data posted. (I hope this explanation makes sense) 
I think you will find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562043/jquery-post-functions-result-data

Comment: You get my problem, thanks for helping!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this should do the trick:

```
var productTable = document.getElementById('ProductTable'), rIndexB;

for(var i = 0; i < productTable.rows.length; i++)
{
    productTable.rows[i].onclick = function()
    {
        rIndex = this.rowsIndexB;
        var bAzon = this.cells[0].innerHTML;

        $.post("AddProductTable.php", {BAzon: bAzon}, function(data){
        $('#load').html(data);
        });

        console.log(bAzon);
    }
}
```